# Normalization between -1 to 1 2D map

Tags: plotting

I use the following code to plot 2D map between Zmax and Zmin but I would like to normalize my intensity map (Z value=`dataT[[3]]`) between -1 to 1. How could I use `Rescaling`  with my code ?

```
func[file_String /; FileExistsQ[file]] := 
 Module[{data, dataT}, data = Import[file, "Table", HeaderLines -> 2];
   dataT = Transpose[data];
  dataT = {dataT[[1]], dataT[[2]], dataT[[3]]};
  data = Transpose[dataT];

  graph = ListDensityPlot[data,
    PlotLabel -> FileBaseName[file],
    PlotRange -> {Full, Full, {Min[data], Max[data]}}, 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {(Min[data] + 
            Max[data])/2, -(Min[data] + Max[data])/2}}])];
  outputFileName = FileBaseName[file];
  Export[ToString[outputFileName] <> ".jpeg", graph] ;
  ]
```

Comment: Try something like `dataT[[3]] = Rescale[dataT[[3]], MinMax[dataT[[3]]], {-1., 1.}];`

Comment: Thank you, it works

Comment: Great. You're welcome.